# Create an MVC4 project -0 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined” Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have downloaded Visual Studio 2015 Community edition.  I have tried to create an MVC project.  I have gone through his process:

```
1) File/New Project/ - C# ASP.NET
2) Select MVC project
3) Project is created
4) Build and click debug
```

The error I get is this: ["0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209573/0x800a1391-javascript-runtime-error-jquery-is-undefined-error).  I have downloaded Visual Studio 2013 Community edition and followed the instructions above and I am prompted with the same error.

I found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yrwhqoT1Bg.  I followed the instructions expect I specified: `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")` as jquery-1.8.2.min.js does not exist, but jquery-1.10.2.min.js does.  I am prompted with the same error after doing this.

What is the problem? This is a new project.  I have added nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")` doesn't exist

Just render the script this way

`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`

and make sure that you have it in your BundleConfig.cs this way

`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));`

Also, if you are using IE browser, then try to use the latest version of JQuery, as the JQuery has some compatibility issues with the IE

Comment: bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")); already exists in the BundleConfig class.  I have added: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") to _Layout.cshtml and it has made no difference.  Have I followed your instructions correctly?

Comment: Are you using IE as your browser? If so, try to use the latest version of JQuery, sometimes its related to the compatibility of JQuery with different  browsers

Comment: Interesting.  It works in Firefox, but not in IE11.  Can you make a change to your answer because it is saying I downvoted it (which must have been by mistake).  I will upvote it for the browser comment.  Thanks.